# What is the F# answer to Haskell's typeclasses and OCaml's functors?

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

It is important to be able to associate a type with a bundle of functions that know how to operate on that type and know its specifics. Modules in F# are intrinsically static, they can be loaded but cannot be used instantiated and parametrized by values and types, let alone passed as parameters and returned from functions.

Both Haskell and OCaml have although very different but nonetheless very useful mechanism that allows such customizations.

What does F# have?

Comment: Here is a blog that discusses this exact question. http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-10-21-fsharp-adhoc-polymorphism/

Comment: There's this concept called object oriented programming that's supposedly supported in F#. I doubt it will ever get much traction though...

Comment: The F# solution might be different depending on what you want to do. Do you have a specific problem at hand?

Comment: @Daniel, yes I do, there is a notion of presence which might be a complex object to one things and a simple one for other things but anyway there are always 10 operations defined on that, i am looking for a answer how in F# i can avoid passing those 10 functions every time when i need to make something on top of those operations provided the presence is generic

Comment: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6603685-parameterized-and-first-class-modules

Comment: Post your specific problem as question, there might be a way to solve it in F#.